# Why isn't the Google QPX Express API returning results for all airlines?

Tags: google-api

I enabled access to the Google QPX Express API to do some analytics on the prices of Delta's tickets and Fare Classes. But the response seems to only include flights from a limited set of airlines.

For example, the following request

```js
{
  "request": {
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": 1
    },
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "JFK",
        "destination": "SFO",
        "date": "2015-02-15",
        "maxStops": 0
      }
    ],
    "solutions": 500
  }
}
```

only returns flights for AS (Alaska Airlines), US (US Air), VX (Virgin America), B6 (JetBlue), and UA (United Airlines).

If I add `"permittedCarriers": [DL]`, then I get an empty response. Likewise, I get an empty response if I leave out `permittedCarriers` and look for flights between Delta hubs (e.g., `"origin": "ATL", "destination": "MSP"`).

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/) suggests that QPX Express is supposed to have most airline tickets available. Is there something wrong with my request? Why am I not seeing any results for Delta?

Comment: Unless you can show that this is down to your own code, it looks very much like Google just isn't supplying that information. You'd have to ask them why.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I just asked them before posting this. If I get a response I'll post it here. I'm asking here too in case a) there's a problem with my request that I don't see or b) someone else has asked Google and knows the answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I received a response from Google's QPX Express help team about missing data for Delta. The response was that

> Delta's data, as well as American Airline's data, is not included in
>   QPX Express search results as a default.  Access to their data
>   requires approval by those carriers.

After informing him that my plans to use the data were for research purpsoses, he responded,

> American and Delta restrict access to their pricing and availability
>   to companies which they approve, which are primarily organizations
>   driving the sale of airline tickets. Unfortunately, requests for
>   access are only being reviewed for companies that plan to use the API
>   for commercial purposes.

Comment: I have also noticed that I don't receive all the results for the same airline. For example, United I only get partial results.